# Question: Using Windows 7, Unauthorized Access Exception when running my application

Tags: c#, windows-7, permissions, directory, userappdatapath

My application is raising an unauthorized access error. While running my application, I try to access a directory in the following location: Application.UserAppDataPath.

The Problem: It says I do not have permission to access the Application.UserAppDataPath directory

Is there a way to set permissions within my application source code?

Something like:

```
Application.UserAppDataPath.SetPermissions()
```

Comment: Please show us your code; you're probably making a mistake.

Comment: If you don't have permission to *access* the path, it stands to reason that you won't have permission to *set permissions on* the path... but you should always have permissions to the user app data.

Comment: The code that throws the exception is this:

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Application.UserAppDataPath));

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at your comment, you say this is your code:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Application.UserAppDataPath);
```

`Application.UserAppDataPath` is a **directory**, not a *file*.  If you try to open that directly, it's the same as trying to open a file one level *below* the AppData folder, which you really don't have permission to do.

Use `Path.Combine` to construct a path to a *file inside* the AppData folder, i.e.

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Application.UserAppDataPath, "settings.xml");
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
```

Of course this is just an example - in reality you should probably be using a sub-folder inside AppData specific to your application.

Comment: This is most likely the cause, and one that I've seen too often. You **definately** want to create a subdirectory underneath AppData that is specific to your application and use that.

Answer (score 2):

Its probably a UAC issue, Try running your application as an elevated process, and see if the error persists

Comment: Thank you.  How do I run it as an elevated process?  Sorry, im a n00b.

Comment: @RedEye: You can right-click on your program's shortcut and choose 'Run as Administrator'.

Comment: @sniperX - +1 - ju got it maing.